# Can we use sounddevice library in Python to play an audio file (.wav or .mp3) on a virtual cable instead of pygame library in Ubantu?

Tags: linux, audio, pygame, virtualization, python-sounddevice

Can I work with Virtual Cables in Ubantu using sounddevice library of Python? I am trying to play an audio file on a Virtual Cable. I have done this using pygame library. Now, I need to do it using sounddevice library. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

ALSA Virtual cables on linux are easily accessible via sounddevice library and we can play audio on them using sounddevice library. Virtual cables made by PulseAudio are not accessible in linux via sounddevice library. If you want to use virtual cables with sonddevice lib on a linux machine then don't create them using PulseAudio :)